# Find text with Selenium in Chrome

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How can I get the text 200 in this case:

```
<p style="margin:0"> 
You can get <big class="tooltip">200</big> more</p>
```

I'm trying using:

```
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> list = _driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[contains(@class, 'tooltip')]"));
```

But can not get the text because the `.Text` property returns an empty string :(

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `ClassName()` with `Xpath`

```
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> list = _driver.FindElements(By.Xpath("//*[@class=\"tooltip\"]/big"));
```

However, I would use CssSelector in this case since css is always preferred over xpath

```
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> list = _driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("big.tooltip"));
```

Considering the element is not inside any `iframe` since it is not throwing any error, I am assuming the wait is needed. Try the following

```
By byCss = By.CssSelector("big.tooltip");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
{
    return d.FindElement(byCss);
});

var text = myDynamicElement.Text;
```

Looks the element is hidden. So `JavaScript` is probably your best try.

```
var text = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return document.querySelector('.tooltip_health_limit').innerHTML;") as string;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the text after you find the element:

```
string text = currentElement.Text;
```

Comment: the problem is that currentElement.Text is empty ;) [link](http://prntscr.com/77tls7)

Comment: is currentElement the one with the big tagname?  Are there other big elements in the DOM with the same class and no text?